# Byte vs Long vs word in GAS assembly

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

This code is accessing all elements correctly(like this):

```
.data
  s : .long 7,2,3,5

.text
.globl _start

_start:

        movl s+4,%eax    # second number in s
        movl $1,%eax
        movl $0,%ebx
        int $0x80
```

But this code gives garbage :

```
.data
  s : .word 7,2,3,5

.text
.globl _start

_start:

        movl s+4,%eax    # third number in s
        movl $1,%eax
        movl $0,%ebx
        int $0x80
```

I am using 64-bit Linux using GAS assembler and using gdb for debugging and checking the register values.

`long` displays exact value while `word` and `byte` give garbage value. `display s` gives `7` for `long` but 131079 for `word`.

I am new to this, is `word` not used in GAS or is there a type conversion going on?

Comment: `long` is 32-bit, `word` 16-bit and `byte` 8-bit. A list is [here](https://gist.github.com/steakknife/d47d0b19a24817f48027). You can take it from here, right? :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom Yes, I get this part. But accessing array like this in `word` or `byte` giving garbage, why?

Comment: Loading two consecutive 16-bit values as a 32-bit value shows you that x86 is little-endian.  There are no types in assembly language, it's all just bytes.

Comment: Show us the exact commands you are using to display as byte word and long. Maybe you are using GDB wrong.

Comment: This `s : .long 7,2,3,5` will assemble into machine code (bytes in hexa): `07 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 05 00 00 00`. This `s : .word 7,2,3,5` will assemble as `07 00 02 00 03 00 05 00`. The `movl s+4,%eax` will load third and fourth word into `eax`, i.e. `eax = 0x00050003` (third word is low 16 bits of `eax`, and fourth is upper 16 bits of `eax`. To load word into `eax` from memory you can use one of `movzx / movsx` (I always forget the GAS suffix-mangled name, like `movzwl` or something like that), or preset upper 16b like `xor eax,eax` (eax=0), then read only `ax`: `movw s+4,%ax`

Comment: I'm betting what is going on is that you change your `.long 7,2,3,5` to either `.byte 7,2,3,5` and `.word 7,2,3,5` and when you do `display s` you get only the right output when you use `.long`. the reason is that by default when you use `display` it assumes you are printing out long's (32-bit values). If you have data that is word (2-byte size) use `display/h &s` for bytes use `display/b &s` and `display/w &s` for 32-bit long

Comment: If you define the array as `.word` you can display all 4 array values as 16-bit words using `display/4h &s`  where the 4 is the number of 16-bit word values to display.

Comment: you are assuming x86 here clearly although not tagged.  the size of these definitions can vary across targets.  and dont be surprised if the size changes in one version one day just like it has in other languages...

Comment: @old_timer: I'm assuming x86 (or x86-64) since it says 64-bit linux and the instructions are x86/x86-64 (albeit using x86 system calls). If the OP said he couldn't assemble this because of unknown instructions etc then I might think he has the wrong architecture. And the sizes for x86 and x86-64 architectures in the documentation do not say their sizes can't be relied upon. It only suggests that they may vary between architectures. Have any evidence they'll change in the future or they can't be relied on? I've seen nothing anywhere that suggests that to be the case in 20+ years.

Comment: an int in C changed sizes in the last 20 years when we went from 16 bit to 32 bit x86 world but long didnt but then then the 32 to 64 bit change we are still sort of in changed things.  But that was another language as I mentioned.  assembly language is worse as it is defined by the assembler, the program, not some standard, and gcc is well known for making up their own tweaks to the chip/processor vendors syntax, and over time change their own.  not necessarily the size of a .word or .long, but at the same time a .word in gcc asm might not match some other x86 asm..  not that it has to

Comment: but when it does, imagine the fallout.  just like the 16 to 32 bit transition, and the 32 to 64 even with stdint and other things being used over time.  the more real thing with gas is that when you change from one target to another .word, .align, are sized differently for that target and if you are only experienced in one, or worse several very easy to get it wrong for the specific task and hand due to habit or too much stuff to memorize and chose to guess rather than look it up or test it...

Comment: @old_timer This isn't a _C_ question. This is an assembly question and one should be considering the binutils documentation for GNU assembler which has made the varying types well known for 20+ years with regards to x86 (and later x86-64). When they added x86-64 the documentation made it clear  x86 and x86-64 follow the same [i386 dependent features](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDependent.html#i386_002dDependent) including the different types. Those are well defined there including their sizes. Nothing has ever said these change.

Comment: Other architectures can in fact have different sizes and words in GNU assembler. But it is clear this is a question that specifically uses x86 or x86-64 which have the same fixed definitions for types and sizes. Long is a synonym for int. Int is 32-bit. quad is 64-bit, word is 16-bit and byte is 8-bit. GDB on the other hand diverges from those GNU assembler definitions.

Comment: Your MAC has probably some x86_64 CPU too (unless it is too old, like a decade, so check what you have), so you can run reasonably (speed wise) some virtualized PC, and install 64b linux inside it. It wouldn't probably do well in terms of games performance, but simple text edit + assembler + debugger should do more than well.